# How to create effect like Van Gogh's stroke brush?

Tags: image-processing, code-request, generative-art

I need to apply Van Gogh's stroke brush effect to a random image
[image: Van Gogh's painting]

Take the following image as an example:[image: Example Image]

Thank you so much if you could help!

Comment: Probably the way to do it is to read [all of these papers on painterly rendering](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/npr/#painterlyrender) and implement one of them in Mathematica.

Comment: Any special reason to do it with Mathematica?

Comment: Many raster image processing programs come with a filter similar to the one you request. Adobe Photoshop is an example of one such.

Comment: You will probably end up doing this in a photo editor.  Some old filter exist that could help you.  [Fantastic Machines PaintEngine (beta)](http://fantasticmachines.com/store/index.php?cPath=24) is free and simple, but not particularly powerful.  The Impressionist filter from Microsoft Image Composer does a better job; I think it used to be freely available but I cannot find a copy now.  There was also a filter called "Xaos Tools Paint Alchemy" which I think was similar to Impressionist; it may be "abandonware" or simply unavailable.

Comment: There is probably a newer, commercial version of this type of filter now but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: It's a bit late now, I admit, but next time could you please avoid using a copyrighted image as the example? Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will...next time.

Comment: There's a Photoshop demo [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/oil-paint-filter.html).

Comment: This shows some of the properties you might want to take into account: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~wangz/project/imsearch/ART/PAMI11/li.pdf

Answer (score 53):

**Edit**

Here is a different approach using `Graphics` to actually draw some brush strokes. I run a `GradientOrientationFilter` on a smaller version of the image to estimate the local image gradient, and use that information to create a collection of randomly shaded lines:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYg7.jpg"];

im = img ~ImageResize~ 200 ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale";

gof = im ~GradientOrientationFilter~ 5;

lines = MapIndexed[{GrayLevel@RandomReal[], 
     Line[{#2 - 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, #2 + 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}}]} &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose@ImageData@gof, {2}];

brush = Image[
   Graphics[lines, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, #1}, {1, #2}} & @@ ImageDimensions[im], 
    Background -> GrayLevel[0.5], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]], 
   ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"];
```

Here is the `brush` image:

[image]

I use a gentle tone-mapping on the original image to equalise the brightness a bit, and then combine the ton-mapped image with the brush strokes.

```
tm = Image`ToneMapHDRI[img, Method -> {"AdaptiveLog", "Bias" -> 1.0}];

Image[0.7 (ImageData@Blur[brush, 2] - 0.6) + ImageData@tm]
```

[image]

You can vary the effect by altering parameters such as the scale of the gradient orientation filter and the length of the lines.

**Original**

Here's an attempt using tone mapping to equalise the brightness across the image, and a gradient filter to enhance outlines. I added some noise to the image before doing the gradient filter, to try and get some variation in the sky. I found it quite difficult to avoid highlighting the jpeg artefacts in the sky.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYg7.jpg"];
tm = Image`ToneMapHDRI[img, Method -> {"AdaptiveLog"}];
edges = ColorNegate[
 img ~ImageEffect~ {"GaussianNoise", 0.1} ~GradientFilter~ 3] ~ImageAdjust~ {0.2, 0, 5};

ImageMultiply[tm, edges]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice - the sky is a problem as you say, just not very van-goghy to start with .. It probably needs some of your hedcut-style texturing...

Comment: @cormullion, I wondered if `ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot` might help with texturing, but it's so slow! I decided to just draw some straight lines with plain old `Line` primitives and it came out quite nicely.

Comment: Like it. Next time let's hope the questioner asks for Seurat or Mondrian or Vaserely... :)

Comment: Your second attempt looks very promising! Perhaps you should find a way to make the randomly shaped brushes depend in a stronger way on the gradient of the image... The twoer and the sky seems to be made with the same brush stroke. Maybe by using a much more contrasted image as a base for that? (Just guessing)

Comment: Results from GradientOrientationFilter look really nice :)!

Comment: @Peltio, I think one would need to segment the different parts of the image like shrx did. It might even be possible to measure the colours in each component and create the image entirely from coloured brush strokes.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `Image`ToneMapHDRI[img, Method -> {"AdaptiveLog", "Bias" -> 1.0}]` is now `tm = ColorToneMapping[img]`.

Answer (score 15):

Mathematica has a few very limited 'effects' built-in:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYg7.jpg"];
oil = ImageEffect[i, {"OilPainting", 4}]
```

[image: oil]

```
boss = ImageEffect[i, {"Embossing", 15}]
```

[image: embossed]

Combining them:

```
ImageAdjust[ImageCompose[boss, {oil, .5}], {1, 0}]
```

[image: combined]

But for the best effects, you'll have to start drinking absinthe...

Comment: Soaking your left ear in absinthe while drinking it may get better results yet.

Comment: @belisarius You go to some interesting parties...

Comment: [Those aren't my parties!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXn2QVipK2o)

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve an effect like this by using [`CurvatureFlowFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurvatureFlowFilter.html) and [`GaborFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GaborFilter.html). The effects are best viewed in full resolution.

Here is the original image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYg7.jpg"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we smooth is nicely with the  [`CurvatureFlowFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurvatureFlowFilter.html):

```
imgsmooth = CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And generate a gradient image of the original image:

```
grad = ImageAdjust@GradientFilter[img, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the gradient image we now compute an image based on a series of `GaborFilters`:

```
gab = ParallelTable[
ImageAdjust[GaborFilter[grad, {40, 7}, {Sin[n], Cos[n]}]], {n, 0, 
Pi, 0.1}];
dirs = ImageApply[Max, gab]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally we compose the final image:

```
res = ImageAdjust[ImageCompose[dirs, {imgsmooth, .5}], {1, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Simply tune the parameters a bit and adjust them to your needs - Van Gogh would certainly be jealous ;).

Comment: Wow! Nicely done.

Comment: Fancy!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Now there's a built-in function for this called `ImageRestyle`

[image]

Comment: Very cool result - thanks for suggesting this built in function!

Answer (score 9):

I see the "Van Gogh" style as a combination of brush strokes and an averaging filter. This is the best result of my effort to simulate this style. I'm sure someone with better knowledge can improve it.

First, we try to split the picture to regions that will have the same brush stroke pattern.

```
orig = Image[ImageData[ImageResize[img, 500]][[All, All, 1 ;; 3]]];(* get rid of the alpha channel which would cause trouble later on *)

wsc = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[orig, 5], 
   MaxDetect[GaussianFilter[orig, 30], Padding -> 1]];
(wsc[[Sequence @@ #]] = wsc[[Sequence @@ (# - {0, 1})]]) & /@ 
  Position[wsc, 0];
wsc // Colorize
```

([image: components])

Next, we select significant parts and create masks for them:

```
partAreas = Count[Flatten[wsc], #] & /@ Range[Max[wsc]];
significantParts = 
 Flatten[Position[partAreas, _?(# > Max[partAreas]/200 &)]];
masks = Table[
  Image[Map[DiscreteDelta[n - #] &, wsc, {2}]], {n, significantParts}]
```

[image: masks]

Then we create brush strokes:

```
brushMasks = (xr = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]; 
    yr = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]; 
    strPlot = 
     StreamPlot[{xr + Sin[2 + (x - y)*5], 
       yr + Sin[2 + (x + y)*5]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      StreamScale -> {.05, .1, 0.001}, 
      StreamPoints -> {2000, .01, .01}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, 
      StreamStyle -> 
       Directive[{GrayLevel[.7], CapForm["Round"], 
         AbsoluteThickness[3]}], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[orig], 
      AspectRatio -> Divide @@ Reverse[ImageDimensions[orig]]];
    GaussianFilter[ImageMultiply[#, Rasterize[strPlot]], 2]) & /@ 
  masks
```

[image: brush stroke masks]

Finally, we apply masks on our image and combine them together:

```
maskedParts = 
 Image[Map[Clip[#, {0, 1}] &, 
     ImageData[ImageSubtract[orig, ColorNegate[#]]], {3}]] & /@ 
  brushMasks
brushedImage = maskedParts[[1]];
n = 2;
While[n <= Length[maskedParts], 
  brushedImage = ImageAdd[brushedImage, maskedParts[[n]]]; n++];
MedianFilter[brushedImage, 1]
```

[image: final image]

There are two issues with this method:

1) Brush strokes take a very long time to generate with my method (using `StreamPlot`); I'm sure there's a better way.

2) The borders between the components can be seen in the final image. I'm not sure how to avoid this.