# Understanding the use of GradientOrientationFilter to achieve a "brushed" effect

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to recreate in Javascript a piece of code that appeared here on *Mathematica*, specifically in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39049).

The user Simon Woods suggested an amazingly efficient way of drawing lines over the picture that seem to follow a natural brushing style.

I'm very new to *Mathematica* and I'm trying to figure out exactly what is happening here:

```
lines = MapIndexed[{GrayLevel@RandomReal[], 
     Line[{#2 - 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, #2 + 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}}]} &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose@ImageData@gof, {2}];
```

I've put together a function that should cover the `GradientOrientationFilter`, outputting the vector directions in radiants and magnitudes. If you want, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/b4zxkcmL/).

I hope someone can help me understand how he is using the outputs of `GradientOrientationFilter`.

---

This is the complete code:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwYg7.jpg"];

im = img ~ImageResize~ 200 ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale";

gof = im ~GradientOrientationFilter~ 5;

lines = MapIndexed[{GrayLevel@RandomReal[], 
     Line[{#2 - 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, #2 + 2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}}]} &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose@ImageData@gof, {2}];

brush = Image[
   Graphics[lines, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, #1}, {1, #2}} & @@ ImageDimensions[im], 
    Background -> GrayLevel[0.5], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]], 
   ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"];
```